# Sequentially assign hostname to multiple hosts using inventory items

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that creates 3 VMs in Hetzner cloud, and assigns their public IPs to an in-memory inventory in order to continue provisioning them.

Directive:

```
- name: Add new servers to dynamic inventory
  add_host:
    name: "{{ item.hcloud_server.ipv4_address }}"
    groups: new_servers
  with_items: "{{ hcloud_info.results }}"
```

And role:

```
- name: Bootstrap server
  hosts: new_servers
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: root
  roles:  
  - bootstrap
```

During this second step, I would need to assign a hostname to each host.

Inventory:

```
[servers]
master.domain.tld
worker1.domain.tld
worker2.domain.tld
```

Checking a few values I see that the `inventory_hostname` fact, gathers VMs IPs instead of the hostnames:

Running debug:

```
- name: Checking
  debug:
    msg: "hostname is {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [1st_IP] => {
    "msg": "hostname is 1st_IP"
}
ok: [2nd_IP] => {
    "msg": "hostname is 2nd_IP"
}
ok: [3rd_IP] => {
    "msg": "hostname is 3rd_IP"
}
```

I found that the hostnames can be gather using the `groups['servers']` fact. The problem is that Ansible tries to assign all 3 hostnames to each host.

Running debug:

```
-  name: Checking inventory
  debug:
    msg: "hostname is {{ groups['servers'] }}"
```

I have this output:

```
ok: [1st_IP] => {
    "msg": "hostname is ['master.domain.tld', 'worker1.domain.tld', 'worker2.domain.tld']"
}
ok: [2nd_IP] => {
    "msg": "hostname is ['master.domain.tld', 'worker1.domain.tld', 'worker2.domain.tld']"
}
ok: [3rd_IP] => {
    "msg": "hostname is ['master.domain.tld', 'worker1.domain.tld', 'worker2.domain.tld']"
}
```

How can I pair each IP with its corresponding hostname?

```
1st_IP = master.domain.tld
2nd_IP = worker1.domain.tld
1st_IP = worker2.domain.tld
```

Comment: Its very unlikely that `inventory_hostname` will have the IP address, it will be exactly the hostname as it appears in inventory file. Do you mean `ansible_hostname`? Also, can you update the question with part of the playbook that produces the output shown?

Comment: Hi @seshadri_c I updated the question with both debug directives and their output!

Comment: I added the snippet that assigns the public IPs to the in-memory inventory as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to never treat `inventory_hostname` as IP address. It's a fallback and unreliable one.

`inventory_hostname` should be a *name*. `srv01` is 'ok' name, 'click4' (or 'postgres4') is a better name.

Use `ansible_host` to specify ip address for Ansible to connect to. I saw many projects struggling with edge cases when they opt for `inventory_hostname` for anything but slugname in ansible output.

Therefore:

```
- name: Add new servers to dynamic inventory
  add_host:
    name: "hc{{ index }}"
    groups: new_servers
    ansible_host: "{{ item.hcloud_server.ipv4_address }}"
  with_items: "{{ hcloud_info.results }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: index
```